# How does one do inequality comparison of unsigned numbers with a subtractor?

Tags: digital-logic

My textbook (Harris and Harris *Digital Design and Computer Architecture*) give the following arrangements for facilitating the comparison of two \$N\$-bit unsigned numbers:

[image]

Given that I am self-studying I am a bit concerned with not fully understanding this. Each subtractor computes \$B-A\$. Now \$A>B \iff B-A<0\$. For two unsigned numbers it's not clear to me why the difference between them should give a 1 on the MSB (as per the picture) if and only if the difference is negative. This would seem to be the case for signed numbers, but why too in the unsigned case?

Comment: Ah, so there's an error here. Noted. I can't quite see why carry out is what matters for unsigned numbers...would you be able to briefly sketch the argument? @periblepsis

Comment: I just use an adder with the subtrahend inverted and the carry in equal 1 and look at the carry out. I could write something. But what in the heck is their "subtractor" made like?

Comment: I can see it for the case \$A = B\$ but not for \$A >B\$.

Comment: Similar(?) question but with an explanation in C: [Wrap around explanation for signed and unsigned variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842215/wrap-around-explanation-for-signed-and-unsigned-variables-in-c)

Comment: @EE18 Here. Look at [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHTwV.png) for 2 bit inputs and a 3-bit result with carry. A>B is the complement of the carry. Not equal to it. A<B or also A=B is what is meant by the carry bit. That's why they wrote A<=B there. A>B = NOT A<=B.

Comment: @EE18 Study [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNSGM.png). I've provided everything I can think of. The direct status bits coming out of the ALU and also all of the possible interpretations of those for the purposes of both unsigned and signed comparisons. It's all there.

Comment: I will certainly do much of that. I guess I’m just trying to CJ Vince myself via something that might look like mathematical proof, but I don’t even know how such a proof would look. If you know of any resources to that end I would also be greatly appreciative, but will definitely look here. @periblepsis

Comment: @EE18 Answer provided. But I really wish you would put in some effort. It isn't rocket science. I was totally ignorant and a complete baffoon in the topic. Yet i was able to navigate this on my own without help or an internet or textbooks or anything else. Just alone with a piece of paper, a pen, and my brain. Seriously, engage yourself. Exercise your ability to think for yourself. Being handed answers on a silver platter stunts your development.

Comment: A question for you, @periblepsis, as I continue to learn about conditional execution. Apologies if this is vague as I'm still trying to work it out in my head. Would it be fair to say that "the underlying hardware just computes values and sets flags" and then it's up to us to use the appropriate conditional instructions (based on whether we "intend" to treat given data as signed or unsigned? You always have a more precise way of phrasing these so I figured I'd ask you if what I said made any sense at all.

Comment: @EE18 Most instruction sets will include a bunch of different conditional jump instructions which examine the condition codes using varying logic. Some of those conditional jumps will only examine the bits important to unsigned, some will examine other bits important to signed. The ALU doesn't care. It's unsigned all the way down to it. (Usually -- which means there have been ALUs that ***do*** have to know and will behave differently. But those ALUs are mostly long since dead and gone as people learned how stupid it was to make a sign-aware ALU.)

Comment: @EE18 So far, I'm just talking about addition/subtraction. Multiplication and division are different animals with respect to sign. Here, you will find it done several ways. Sometimes, unsigned only where software handles the "fix ups." Sometimes, signed. Sometimes, accepting signed for one, unsigned for the other, or any of the four possible pairings and dealing uniquely with each. So while there are a lot of similar ways, you can't always predict them as well as you can an adder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. \$\overline{A}+A+1=2^N\$, where \$N\$ is the bits in the unsigned word. So:

   \$\overline{A}+1=2^N-A\$
2. Suppose \$A \gt B\$. Then \$-A\lt-B\$. Then:

   \$2^N-A\lt 2^N-B\$
3. Substituting #1 above into #2, then \$\overline{A}+1\lt 2^N-B\$. Therefore:

   \$B+\overline{A}+1\lt 2^N\$
4. Since the sum in #3 is less than \$2^N\$ it follows there's no carry-out.
5. But \$B+\overline{A}+1=B-A\$. In short, subtracting \$A\$ from \$B\$ to make the comparison.

So I've proven that there is no carry-out when performing \$B-A\$ when \$A\gt B\$.

Therefore, a carry-out of 0 means \$A\gt B\$ and a carry-out of 1 means \$A\le B\$.

Comment: So how do you establish *A≠B*?

Comment: @greybeard Not in the OP question. And I want the OP to spend time working things out more than he has been.

Comment: Straight from the question's initial title, though.

Comment: @greybeard Not in the question and not in his comment about a proof. Why are you pressing?

Comment: That answer is very abstract. Can't you supplement it with some concrete examples say with sample 4bit operands.

Comment: @6v6gt The OP wrote, *"but I don’t even know how such a proof would look. If you know of any resources to that end I would also be greatly appreciative"*, in a comment. A proof is, out of its own need, abstract. And that's along the lines of how one may look. Besides, I provided a concrete example in a comment to the OP. (I also provided a method for \$\ne\$ that already provides one possible answer to greybeard's question, too. I'm sure he already saw it. Which is partly why I asked him about his motivation.) Best to await the OP, I think.

Comment: For my future self: note that the underlying subtractor hardware does not care whether you intend for \$A,B\$ to signed or unsigned. It simply computes \$B + \overline{A} + 1\$ (that is, it always "thinks" it's dealing with 2s complement signed numbers). It is then up to us to determine, based on the \$C,Z,N,V\$ flags (in e.g. an ARM architecture) and based on whether we intend to treat the data as signed or unsigned to determine the result. Thus, here, periblepsis has very nicely shown how \$A>B\$ unsigned is equivalent to (though it was not noted in the answer, notice how each step is not...

Comment: ... just a "then" but, in fact, an "if and only if") there being 0 carry out when we perform $\B - A\$.

Comment: One thing I do not understand...what goes wrong when we try to use this proof to show that \$B \geq A\$ signed if and only if the carry out from \$B-A\$ is 1. To be clear, this is WRONG, but it would be what one would suspect if one used the above. Instead, the truth is that of course  \$B \geq A\$ signed if and only if \$\overline{N \oplus V}\$. But I'm hoping you can point out to me where we use that \$A,B\$ are unsigned in the above.

Comment: @EE18 `it always "thinks" it's dealing with 2s complement signed numbers` -- NO!! It always thinks it is dealing with ***unsigned*** numbers. It doesn't know about signs, at all. So write a different `note to self`. Or else you will be in a mess.